# Can NUnit TImeoutAttribute override NUnit Console Runner timeout?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0, nunit-console

I currently use NUnit Console to run my NUnit 3 tests.  I pass a **Timeout** command-line option to NUnit Console Runner.  This timeout is about 30 minutes, but I have one test that takes longer than 30 minutes, so I put a **TimeoutAttribute** on that one test.  I assumed that **TimeoutAttribute** would take precedence over the global **Timeout** passed to the console runner.  That does not seem to be the case.  Seems like the **TimeoutAttribute** should take precedence or is there some other way I can do this besides changing the **Timeout** value passed on the command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have properly applied the `TimeoutAttribute`, it takes precedence over the nunit-console command-line option. The option could more properly be called "defaultTimeout".

I'm "assuming" because you haven't included any code that shows where you actually placed the attribute or shown the command-line you are running. If you add those to the question, I'll correct this answer as needed.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the behavior that I saw.  I pass a timeout of 30 minutes (1800000) using --timeout:1800000 to Nunit Console.  In the test code, I apply the Timeout attribute with a value of 2400000, which should have been 40 minutes.  However, the test actually timed out in 30 minutes.

Comment: Well, turns out that I had started my NUnit run job prior to the build completing with the Timeout attribute change.  Thus, I ran against old code that didn't have the Timeout set properly.  Turns out it works as you indicated.  Sorry about that.

Comment: That happens. I used to like manually running the build and test steps separately, but now I just have Test force a Build to avoid exactly this problem.

Comment: I would do that too except I have several jobs that run different test lists against the same build so that I can distribute the load and shorten the test run time.